# iOS9 Storyboard "Setting empty vector for variable" exception - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: objective-c, exception, ios9, uistoryboard

I'm running into an issue where my main storyboard got corrupted after I messed around with it, and I get the following cryptic error message. The app catches error in `main()` and is followed by `SIGABRT` with the following exception:

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '{objective 0x147dc56e0: <1:-25.3333> + <1:1>*0x147dc39b0.posErrorMarker{id: 91} +
 <1:0.125>*0x147dc50e0.negError{id: 90} +
 <1:-0.125>*0x147e2e300.marker{id: 77} +
 <1:0.125>*0x147e2e300.slack{id: 78} +
 <1:0.125>*0x147e2e350.marker{id: 81} +
 <1:-1>*0x147e2e440.marker{id: 87} +
 <1:-0.125>*0x147e436b0.marker{id: 63} +
 <1:0.125>*0x147e437f0.marker{id: 72} +
 <1:-0.125>*0x147e764c0.marker{id: 55} +
 <1:0.125>*0x147e88820.marker{id: 52}}:
 internal error.  Setting empty vector for variable 0x147dc1b90.negError{id: 48}.'
```

Setting another storyboard to be the main interface has the app starting up correctly.

**How can I find the element that is causing "Setting empty vector for variable" storyboard exception?**

Comment: Don't you have a variable name after `Setting empty vector for variable` to help you identify the object causing issue?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

In case it helps anyone else, I was getting an `Setting empty vector for variable` error with use of a UIStackView where the `spacing` property was not set.

Not sure if it's the actual cause, or just a weird correlation, but **setting spacing to a non-zero value prevents this error for me**.

Comment: This was a lifesaver

Comment: @jusynth one more life saved +

Answer (score 1):

try using `po 0x147dc1b90` in the debugger console, where `0x147dc1b90` is your variable address, which you can see in the last line, to see more details

Comment: Can you explain more after get the address, Thx

Answer (score 1):

For me it was calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` without main queue was the issue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```